# Dynamically Generate Editable PDF exactly as same in the html form using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I am working on dynamic generation of web forms and I am generating editable PDF using iTextSharp.

Following is the screenshot for the form:

[image]

Form can be even more lengthy with various ***checkboxes, radio button groups, tables***.

Without any change in the order of the fields in the html form, is it possible to create an editable form using `iTextSharp`?.

I have already generated the editable fields in a PDF document and my code is:

```
//Creating a document

    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);

    FileStream pdfFileStream = new FileStream("D:\\new.pdf", FileMode.Create);

//Writing to PDF
    using (PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, pdfFileStream))
    {
        //Opening the document for writing
        document.Open();
        PdfContentByte cb = pdfWriter.DirectContent;

        Paragraph para = new Paragraph("Name");
        document.Add(para);

        //Creating the text box starts here --->
        TextField _text = new TextField(pdfWriter, new Rectangle(100, 806, 170, 790), "Name");
        _text.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
        _text.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        //_text.Options = TextField.MULTILINE;
        _text.Text = "";
        pdfWriter.AddAnnotation(_text.GetTextField());
        cb = pdfWriter.DirectContent;

        //Creating the text box ends here ---<

        //Creating the RadioButton group starts here ---->

        PdfFormField _radioGroup = PdfFormField.CreateRadioButton(pdfWriter, true);
        _radioGroup.FieldName = "Gender";

        string[] genders = { "Male", "Female" };

        RadioCheckField genderRadioCheckField;
        PdfFormField radioGField;

        for (int i = 0; i < genders.Length; i++)
        {
            genderRadioCheckField = new RadioCheckField(pdfWriter, new Rectangle(40, 806 - i * 40, 60, 788 - i * 40), null, genders[i]);

            genderRadioCheckField.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY;
            genderRadioCheckField.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CIRCLE;

            radioGField = genderRadioCheckField.RadioField;
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase(genders[i], new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12)), 70, 790 - i * 40, 0);
            _radioGroup.AddKid(radioGField);

        }

        pdfWriter.AddAnnotation(_radioGroup);
        cb = pdfWriter.DirectContent;
        //Creating the RadioButton group ends here ----<



        //Closing the document for writing
        document.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Completed");
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Now, the code generates the Editable PDF with the Text Field and a Radio Button.

**My problem:**

Can I dynamically generate the editable PDF form with the fields having the **exact order and position** as the html form has?

So, wherever the form fields, is it possible to get the ***exact order & location of the fields(Width & height)*** as the html form has?

**Note:** I am creating the forms dynamically.

Comment: I really don't know what "exact position" of an HTML field means unless your positioning things `fixed`. Most modern browsers will render HTML similarly but I don't think that your `x` and `y` coordinates will match across Firefox, Chrome, IE, Opera, Edge, whatever. So you're going to have to just make that part up, pick a browser or build your own and solve that. Once you have that then you should be able to translate those to PDF coordinate space although you'll need to also handle HTML's "infinite page length" and convert that to PDF's fixed page size.

Comment: Could you please explain me what the "infinite page length"?

Comment: If you come up with a scheme of decorating your elements that is pretty solid then you could parse using your scheme as opposed to trying to determine layout via html? For example: class="row1 column2 checkbox". You could make a pretty simple parser.

Comment: Are you saying each & every thing should be generated with the table format in PDF?

Comment: At some point you will have to limit your scope of what is capable of being reproduced in pdf. If you limit the html form layout to tables or "grid like" structures then the whole export to pdf will be a lot smother.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that. Render the view as html in a string variable and then convert the html string to pdf. I am using EO.PDF which provides a method to convert from html to pdf.